# Updating SharePoint Online list with more than 100000 records using CSOM(caml query)

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online, csom, caml

I am having a SharePoint list with records (1,70,000). Trying to update a lookup column in the list using CAML Query.
Indexing is present for both the columns Columns.

**CAML Query**: `oQuery.ViewXml = oQuery.ViewXml = $@"<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='DocumentUniqueID' /><Value Type='Text'>{dtExcel.Rows[i]["DocumentUniqueID"]}</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='SequenceNo' /><Value Type='Number'>{dtExcel.Rows[i]["SequenceNo"]}</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>";`

**ERROR:** The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator